# openpyxl multi-line strings into cells using for loop

Tags: python, list, alignment, openpyxl, multiline

I'm trying to write multi line into celles using Openpyxl the list below. It only writeS the last word. I found the wrap_text alignment property but it does not work when I put in for boucle, any idea why ?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = Workbook()
ws=wb.active
my_list = ["A", "B", "C","D"]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
    ws['B2']=str(my_list[i])+"\n"
    ws['B2'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

wb.save("C:\Temp\AttachmentCopie.xlsx")
```

Comment: You're overwriting the contents of `ws['B2']` with every iteration.

Comment: yes i want to write in this cells only, I m trying to multi line in this cells

Comment: Well, create a multi-line string and write to the cell once, otherwise you're replacing what you've written with the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the answer, thanks to PApostol for the tip :

wb = Workbook()
ws=wb.active
my_list = ["A", "B", "C","D"]
join_my_list = '\n'.join(my_list)
ws['B2']=join_my_list
ws['B2'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

wb.save("C:\Temp\AttachmentCopie.xlsx")
```